# Does liveness failure that happened in concurrency exist in java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8

i will try to reproduce following code that mentioned in Effective Java(second edition).
Belongs to Chapter 10 Concurrency Item 66.

```
public class StopThread {
   private static boolean stopRequested;

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Thread backgroudThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while(!stopRequested) {
                       i ++;
                }
             }
      });
      backgroudThread.start();

      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
      stopRequested = true;
   }
}
```

According to author's description when you run above procedure segments the backgroupdThread will not terminated. But i cannot reproduce it in my machine which set Java8 environment. So does this issue has been optimized in Java latest version?

**UPDATED**
I try it again in linux operation system(redhat). It always not terminate.                                                                   Before i run it in Win7 operation system COREi5. It always terminate.

PS:                                                                                                   In linux operation system(redhat). If run according above code and program will not terminate. But if i add "System.out.println(i)" after "i++" in "while" loop. At this time. Program will terminate always. It's my new discover. Please post your answer if you know why. I will continue to drill these series issues until i find it real reason.

Comment: Sad fact of life: A multithreading issue not producing visible effects doesn't mean it's not going to be a problem. It's one of the reasons writing multithreaded code is such a pain.

Comment: Does the author actually say it *will* not be terminated or *might* not be terminated? There's definitely no guarantee that it will terminate here.

Comment: @Jon the author of effective java is Josh Bloch, so I think we can assume the later.

Comment: @Voo: I *suspect* the latter as well - but I don't have a copy of EJ to hand right now.

Comment: Yeah, please refer to alfasin's answers. It reference sentence that belongs to EJ. the author wrote:"On my machine, however, the program never terminates: the background thread loops forever!"

Answer (score 3):

Well, if to be more accurate, the author wrote:

> On my machine, however, the program never terminates: the background
>   thread loops forever!

Now you can still argue with that cause he obviously didn't run this program "forever" but you get the idea.

By the way, on **my** machine, the program never terminates either (JDK 1.7.0_45) 
By the way 2: if we want it to terminate, all we have to do is declare `stopRequested` to be `volatile`

**UPDATE:** 
In order to provide more context for those who don't have the book (and you *really* should get it!), the author explains later on that the reason this *could* happen is due to the compiler that detects that `stopRequested` is not changed locally and hence allows the following  optimization:

```
while(!stopRequested) {
      i ++;
}
```

becomes:

```
if (!stopRequested)
    while(true) {
          i ++;
    }
```

JVM hotspot does this kind of optimization (called *hoisting*). If you want to drill deeper into *why* is it a legit optimization, you should do some reading: [JLS §17.4.3 Programs and Program Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3)

Comment: Yeah, your reference from author very accurately. And i am very confuse why your machine can run this problem like author's description. But i cannot.

Comment: @Ivan_Wang, Computer architecture is evolving all the time.  The java language spec intentionally leaves some aspects of multi-threading unspecified so that JVM implementers will have the freedom to make the most efficient use of different architectures and different operating systems.  If every JVM had to behave exactly like every other JVM, then most JVMs would be much less efficient.  So be warned!  If the spec says something _might_ happen, then write your code accordingly even if you can't prove that it _does_ happen on any given machine.

Comment: @alfasin Thanks you for post updated content. I don't know whether hoisting optimization also exists in current Java version. Because according my understanding for this optimization,backgroudThread will never stop without sync. May be i have miss understanding. Please help me to point where i was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan_Wang optimization is something the compiler *can* do, it's optional not mandatory. I'm sure Java 8 implements hoisting as well, probably not in this specific case though. And yes, your understanding is correct, using this optimization means that backgroudThread will never stop.

Comment: For the record, the load is reliably hoisted on my JVM 8.

Comment: Just as a side note, the resulting optimized code is not even required to modify `i` inside the loop. So its more like `if(!stopRequested) while(true);` But since it is not guaranteed that after starting the thread the execution of that code begins in less than one second, even if that optimization takes place the thread *might* terminate on some runs.

Answer (score 2):

No, the author says it never terminates *on his machine*. That's entirely possible and exactly the point he's trying to make: shared access to mutable data should be synchronized, not only to ensure atomicity, but also to ensure *visibility*.

While assignment to `boolean` is atomic ,the background thread *might* not **see** the main thread's change to `stopRequested`.

The author also proposes an easy fix: declare `stopRequested` as `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

> According to author's description when you run above procedure segments the backgroundThread will not terminated.

I don't have the book in front of me, but I strongly suspect that is doesn't say that.

I think it actually says words to the effect that the background thread **might not** be terminated.  The words "will not" and "might not" mean different things ...

**UPDATE** - see @alfasin's answer for what Bloch actually wrote.

---

> But i cannot reproduce it in my machine which set Java8 environment. So does this issue has been optimized in Java latest version?

No.  Not "optimized".  Just different.

What is actually going on is that the program has strayed into an area where the Java Language Specification says that the behaviour is not specified.  In particular, it is not **guaranteed** that the background thread will see the change that the main thread makes to the flag.  But it might see it anyway ... depending on all sorts of things.

It is not surprising that you can't reproduce this on your Java 8.  You *could* have difficulty reproducing it on older Java platforms as well.   And in a sense, it is this "difficulty" that is the reason that this kind of issue is so gnarly.

Answer (score 1):

> So does this issue has been optimized in Java latest version?

It is the other way around: this "issue" exists precisely *due* to optimizations allowed by the Java Memory Model. These provisions have definitely not been removed from the Java 8 specification, and are here to stay. They offer significant benefits in terms of multithreaded performance.

Java provides specific language features which allow your example to work properly, but it does not force these features to be used everywhere; it leaves it to programmer's discretion to apply them, together with their performance cost, only where they are needed.

FYI, I have run the exact code from your question (plus a missing `throws` declaration) and the program reliably does not terminate on my OpenJDK 1.8.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.Just like you said, you run my code and program certainly does not terminate. But i run it always terminated. If you run it multi times, does it not terminate stably? Or it not terminate occasionally.Thanks.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, it *always* fails to terminate on my machine. But since the JMM states that the behavior at your side is as legitimate as mine, this is nothing unusual.